# Returning XMLReader

Tags: .net, xml, xmlreader

I am trying to return an XMLReader from a data access class that calls a stored proc to run a FOR XML query. The problem is, I can't call close() on the sql connection when I return the xmlreader or the reading will terminate. The class that calls for the xmlreader doesn't know anything about a sql connection so it can't be in charge of closing the connection. How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

You could to build a `XmlDocument` and to return it, so you can have that database connection closed.

Comment: The problem is, this xml could be up to 200mb, that's why I was trying the reader approach. Do I really want to hold a 200mb xmldocument in memory?

Comment: In this case, you'll need to keep that connection open, or to make your data access layer disposable, so you can call it with `using`

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous method to wrap the call.

For example, assuming you have a datalayer class, add a similar method to the data layer:

```
public delegate void DoSomethingInvoker();
class DataLayer
{
   //myReader needs to be declared externally in other to access it from the doSomething delegate
   public void MethodThatGetsAsXmlReader(XmlReader myReader, DoSomethingInvoker doSomething)
   {
      myReader = GetXmlReaderFromDB();
      doSomething();
      CloseDbConnection();      //close connections, do cleanup, and any other book keeping can be done after the doSomething() call
   }
}
```

To call/use it, you simply do this in your high level class

```
DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
XmlReader myReader = null;  //variables declared outside the scope of the anonymous method are still accessible inside it through the magic of closures
dl.MethodThatGetsAsXmlReader(myReader, delegate()
   {
      //do all work that involves myReader here
      myReader.read();   
      Console.out.println(myReader.value);
   });
//at this point myReader is closed and cannot be used
```

Basically, you pass the code you want to execute to the datalayer, the data layer fetches the xmlreader, calls your code against it, and then does cleanup.

I use a similar technique for wrapping transaction logic in my code

```
DataLayer dl = new DataLayer();
dl.Transaction(delegate()
   {
        dl.DbCall1();
        dl.DbCall2();
        dl.DbCall3();
    });
```

It makes the code nice and readable, while still keeping it organized and layered;